# Regular Expression URL ReWrite

Tags: regex, sharepoint-2010

This is my first post on here and I must admit my knowledge of regular expressions is minimal.

We have recently upgraded our internal intranet from sharepoint 2003 to 2010. During this process we broke down a single site into multiple site collections which added `/sites` into the URL for the different sites

e.g.

```
http_://intranet/global > http_://intranet/sites/global
http_://intranet/workplaces > http_://intranet/sites/workpaces
```

I have tried playing around with regular expressions to re-write static URLs to be rewritten to include `/sites`

[**Here is my attempt**](http://regex101.com/r/aC6dL3)

You should see the last two records are not being wr-written correctly. Can anyone help me create the correct rule?

Comment: You should include the regex within the question too. That way, should the link stop working, people will still be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

**REGEX**
You may use this:

> /^(http://[^/]+)?/(?!(?:sites|SitePages)/)(.*)$/mg

with this replacement

> \1/sites/\2

**DEMO**
http://regex101.com/r/zH6dZ5

**RESULTS**

```
    http://intranet/global                  >  http://intranet/sites/global
    /sites/global                           >  /sites/global
    /page/file.ext                          >  /sites/page/file.ext
    /sites/other                            >  /sites/other
    /page.ext                               >  /sites/page.ext
    /intranet/global                        >  /sites/intranet/global
    http_://intranet/SitePages/default.aspx > http_://intranet/SitePages/default.aspx
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thankyou very much for the response. I have just run through a few tests and your recommendations looks great. I have one final question though...
The our landing page URL is: http_://intranet/SitePages/default.aspx
It would seem this is being re-written to http_://intranet/sites/SitePages/default.aspx which fails - do you know a away to exclude this URL?

Comment: I have updated my post with a new regex and demo including your landing page case. HTH

Comment: Hi, thanks again... wow that was a quick reply.

Just found an issue with the expression:

http://regex101.com/r/qQ2mB2 - The first line is rewritting the wrong way round.

Comment: I leave you as an exercise this issue :)